# Database design for a simple payment transactions

Tags: database-design

I need to design a rudimentary database payment transaction.  Where I can assign a user with a balance and whenever they purchase something, I manually enter the value on the application and their balance should decrease.

This is the design I have currently.

```
AccountTable
Id Identity PK
Balance decimal (18,2)
CustomerID FK(Customer)

Withdrawal Table
Id Identity PK
Amount decimal(18,2)
Timestamp datetime
comment varchar(100)
AccountID FK(AccountTable)

Deposit Table
Id Identity PK
Amount decimal(18,2)
Timestamp datetime
comment varchar(100)
AccountID FK(AccountTable)
```

I am not sure how I'd update the balance.

This a ASP.NET MVC site, so I am thinking whenever a transaction takes place, (either buying product) or topping up their account, I'd have a process in a controller to get sum of deposits and sum of transactions and do Deposits - Withdrawals and update the Balance.

Is this an OK choice, or a very bad idea? are there any simple improvements I could do in the design.

Comment: Why not using a single table _Movements_ where you record the withdrawals with the negative sign and the deposits with a positive one?. Then when you need to display the balance you have just an SQL SUM to run

Comment: Agree that a single Transaction table is probably the way to go. As for updating balance, either don't, and create a view that does the summing (very simple solution, but may get too slow if there are too many transactions), or use a trigger so that however the transactions are updated, the balance will still be correct.